# Image copying to pasteboard in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, copy, uipasteboard

I am having an app in which I want to copy an image and paste it in the sms app.

I am using the below code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Heritage" ofType:@"png"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    [pasteboard setData:data forPasteboardType:@"public.png"];

}
```

I have got this code after searching on google and there are lots of code but somehow none of them seems to work for me.

When I run the app and go to sms app and press, the paste option doesn't show me there.

Heritage.png is an image in my app's bundle.

Where am I doing any mistake?

Please let me know.

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I got a solution of my own.

I didn't enable the keyboard extension to allow full access.

Just forgot to set "RequestOpenAccess" to "YES".

[image]

Hope someone else does not forget to check this small things.

Thanks...